# Backup and restore in sonarqube

Tags: database, sonarqube, backup, restore, recovery

I would like to backup my SonarQube production server. Can you please help with below two queries:

1\ What all things backup needs to be taken (e.g. database or which all folders from SonarQube home)

2\ Is there any solution already available which can be used directly to take backup of SonarQube.

Thanks and Regards,
Deepti

Answer (score 2):

We regularly do backups in our company, and for that we only backup two things:

1. the database - because it contains all the data and this is the only thing based on the upgrade notice you need for a restore https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/upgrading/
2. the ./extensions/plugin folder - because you never know, what was the version of which plugin afterwards. and you might have a custom plugin, or one which is not in the marketplace, which you will sure forget about

There is no reason to backup the elastic search data, as sonarqube will create all the necessary information on startup. Just be aware, that the first startup will take some time, depending on the amount of data you have stored.

As those two things are actually pretty straight forward, i am not sure if there is really a tool which can help you with that.